# How can run js in v8's none main thread?

Tags: javascript, c++, multithreading, v8

In v8 engine,js code can only run in main thread.I aim at running js code in none main thread , in this way CPU-intensive task could not preempt the cpu time of main thread.
But i just have no idea how to achieve the goal.

OK,i remove the tag of `node.js` of this question, i don't care the skill of how to take advantage of  multicore in node.js.I am writting an implement of thread based on native v8 api.Please don't tell the solution that used in node.js.In fact , i desire someone give me some guide based on v8's c++ api.

[This link](https://kkaefer.com/node-cpp-modules/#worker-function) explain why we can't use V8 code in none main thread , in user-defined thread you can only run native c++ code.This is no solution?

Comment: What makes you think that v8 can only run in the main thread?

Comment: what environment you run the js?(e.g. In browser or node.js, etc). Most environment support running code on other threads. For instance, node.js you can use cluster. Check the manual for detail.

Comment: What does this have to do with C++?

Comment: Note: You can use [`child_process.fork()`](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_fork_modulepath_args_options) for multi-process concurrency for long-running, synchronous JavaScript.

Comment: i know child_process.fork(),but i wanna implement thread in node.child_process.fork() or cluster is not my goal.I want to make node works like WebWorker in browser.In fact,there are several of threads in node,but in there thread,you can not run v8's function.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to dive to such a low level. Node is mature enough to have higher level options available for these kinds of things.

You can use the child_process module to fork your main process with `child_process.fork()`. You can then let your CPU intensive synchronous tasks run in parallel without affecting the main process.

If you want to take advantage of multiple processes as standard functionality for your app, then the [cluster module](http://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html) is what you're after. The node core cluster module is the way most people take advantage of multi-core systems by running multiple node processes and delegating work to them. The cluster module takes care of the nitty gritty details for you and makes it pretty easy. Just check out some of the examples in [the documentation](http://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html).